# Parsing Python code using ANTLR in Java with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, antlr4

### Context

I am trying to parse some Python code, and find a function inside a `.py` file using ANTLR. However I am experiencing some difficulties understanding how to use ANTLR within java.

### build.gradle

The following `build.gradle` file content is used to include ANTLR:

```
plugins {
    ...

    // Allow using antler.
    id 'antlr'
}

dependencies {
...

    // Include support for ANTLR runtime dependency.
    implementation 'org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.13.1'

    }
```

And based on [this example 1](https://github.com/teverett/antlr4example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/khubla/antlr4example/Main.java) I have included the files: `Python3Parser.g4` and `Python3Lexer.g4` files in the same directory as the `EditPython.java` file below. And based on [this example 2](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python/python3/Python3) I included the `Python3LexerBase.java` and `Python3ParserBase.java` (which I believe eventually yield the `Python3Lexer.g4` and `Python3Parser.g4` files when one runs:

```py
python transformGrammar.py
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 -o gen *.g4
```

### MWE

This is a minimal class that tries to use the Python3Parser object.

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNode;

public class EditPython {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
      System.out.println("Please provide a Python code snippet as an argument.");
      return;
    }

    String pythonCode = args[0];
    modifyFunctionDocumentation(pythonCode);
  }

  public static void modifyFunctionDocumentation(String pythonCode) {
    // Parse Python code to get the tree
    Python3Lexer lexer = new Python3Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(pythonCode));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    Python3Parser parser = new Python3Parser(tokens);
    ParseTree tree = parser.file_input();

    // Traverse the tree to find and modify documentation
    Python3Parser.File_inputContext ctx = parser.file_input();
    Python3Parser.StmtContext stmtContext = ctx.stmt(0); // Assuming it's the first statement
    if (stmtContext.funcdef() != null && stmtContext.funcdef().NAME().getText().equals("some_function")) {
      // Assuming docstring is represented as STRING() in AST
      Python3Parser.FuncdefContext funcDefContext = stmtContext.funcdef();
      TerminalNode stringNode = funcDefContext.STRING();
      if (stringNode != null) {
        String docstring = stringNode.getText();
        System.out.println("Found the function: some_function");
        System.out.println("Docstring: " + docstring);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Function some_function found, but no docstring.");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Function some_function not found in the provided code.");
    }
  }
}
```

### Issue

However when I compile it, it returns:

```
                                ^
EditPython.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    Python3Lexer lexer = new Python3Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(pythonCode));
    ^
```

Because I did not import `Python3Lexer`. However when I do `com.someproject.somefolder.Python3Lexer`, it says:

```
EditPython.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.someproject.somefolder.Python3Lexer;
                                  ^
```

Because the `Python3Lexer.g4` file is not a `Python3Lexer.java` file.

### Question

How can I include the `Python3Lexer` file in the Java code such that I can use the `Python3Parser` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to run `transformGrammar.py`. That is only needed if you are going to use Python as the target language (Java is your target language).

To parse a python source file in Java and print the function names inside the `.py` file, do the following:

### 1. download files

Create a directory and download the following files:

```
wget https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/python/python3/Python3Lexer.g4
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/python/python3/Python3Parser.g4
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/python/python3/Java/Python3LexerBase.java
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/python/python3/Java/Python3ParserBase.java
```

(I used the command line `wget`, but you can simply download them through your browser too)

### 2. main class

In that same directory, create a file called `Main.java` with the following contents:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String source = "def foo():\n    pass\n\ndef quared(n):\n    return n * n";

        System.out.println(source + "\n");
        
        Python3Lexer lexer = new Python3Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
        Python3Parser parser = new Python3Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new Python3ParserBaseListener() {

            // funcdef
            //  : 'def' name parameters ('->' test)? ':' block
            //  ;
            @Override
            public void enterFuncdef(Python3Parser.FuncdefContext ctx) {
                System.out.println("name=" + ctx.name().getText());
            }

        }, parser.file_input());
    }
}
```

### 3. generate parser

To generate the lexer and parser classes, execute the following command:

```
java -jar antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar *.g4
```

### 4. compile java

To compile all Java source files, execute the following command:

```
javac -cp antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar *.java
```

### 5. run main class

To run the `Main` class, execute the following command when you're on Linux or Mac:

```
java -cp .:antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar Main
```

On Windows do:

```
java -cp .;antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar Main
```

You should see the following being printed to your console:

```
def foo():
    pass

def quared(n):
    return n * n

name=foo
name=quared
```